# Re-gaining root access to an EC2 EBS-boot image

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, password, amazon-ebs

I'm using an Alestic image which disables root SSH logins, but provides a user "ubuntu" with NOPASSWD sudo privileges. See [here](http://alestic.com/2009/04/ubuntu-ec2-sudo-ssh-rsync).

In the course of trying to add a new user to the sudoers file I inadvertantly created another line for the "ubuntu" user, this time *without* NOPASSWD. I have now apparently lost root access to this machine.

Is there some way to mount the EBS root volume on a different instance (fixing the sudoers file) and then re-launch the server?

Or am I totally screwed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mount the EBS volume to another instance.

1. Set the problematic instance to "Stop"
2. Identify the EBS volume mounted to the problematic instance via the instance-id it should be listed like any other EBS volume on the web console.
3. Detach the drive and mount it to a working instance
4. Modify it
5. Detach it from the working instance
6. Re-attach the drive back to your original problematic instance and set to "Start"

Comment: Haven't had the opportunity to test this, but marked as answered since I assume it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the ubuntu user has no password and the problem is that sudo requires a password have you tried giving the ubuntu user a password ?

```
ubuntu@host$ passwd
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Edit - I've just had an opportunity to test this and can confirm that setting a password for the ubuntu user will let you regain access to sudo.

Having a password on the account is a Good Thing <sup>tm</sup> anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hadn't considered that maybe there would be no password set. Unfortunately `passwd` asks for my current password. I think the 'ubuntu' account may have been created with `$ adduser --disabled-password ubuntu`. Any other ideas?

Comment: I only tested it with a user that had no password rather than a --disabled-password user. I've set this up but can't find a way around it atm.