# No public DNS on AWS after reattaching EBS volume to new instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I was following the instructions here:

Re-gaining root access to an EC2 EBS-boot image

```
  http://serverfault.com/questions/234061/re-gaining-root-access-to-an-ec2-ebs-boot-image
```

And I successfully completed this stage:

```
  Re-attach the drive back to your original problematic instance and set to "Start"
```

But then the new instance spun up, but it has no public DNS nor any public IP. How can I be sure it has the same settings as the previous instance that it was built from?

To be clear, I took the old instance and clicked "Launch more like this", and that is how I created the new instance. But it seems to have different settings.

Comment: Can you expand on "no public DNS"? You can't do nslookups? Maybe output the IP details - in unix type "ip a".

Comment: I mean, if I look here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Instances:sort=desc:dnsName, then I don't see any entry in the columns "Public DNS" and "Public IP". The problem is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941704/ec2-instance-has-no-public-dns. However, these instances have always had Public DNS set to "Yes".

Comment: Post a screen shot please, we can't see your console. You probably have to attach a network interface and then an elastic IP to that instance.

Comment: I gave up on this. I created a new instance, and I clicked the "Enable Auto Public DNS" option when I was creating the instance.