# EC2 unable to reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, selinux

I enabled selinux to make some tests (with `enforcing`) and now my AWS instance is unable to boot.
From the instance screenshot I see that it can't start some services like `login`

How can I recover the instance?

here a screenshot of the errors
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like none of your files have SELinux labels.

You should first set SELinux to `permissive`. You will need to [start a new instance and attach your existing instance's EBS volume to it](https://serverfault.com/q/234061/126632) to make this change and allow you to boot it again.

After you boot the system with SELinux in permissive mode, you can relabel all your files with `restorecon -rv /`, then finally you can reboot in `enforcing` mode.

---

For future reference you should *never* set SELinux to disabled. If you must "disable" it for something, you should either set SELinux to permissive, or set a [single SELinux domain to permissive](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Permissive_Domains) (for a single service).

Comment: You can usually also `touch /.autorelabel` to force relabelling on subsequent boot.

Comment: @bodgit Because EC2 doesn't provide live access to the VM console, I prefer to do this manually.

Comment: the current app doesn't have selinux enable so when I setup the AWS i disable it and setup the same machine there, but now we want to enable it so i was trying to make some tests. Basically if I want to enable it on the live server I need to set `permissive` use `restorecon -rv /` and then use `enforcing` right?

Comment: @Sebastiano That's correct.